# Missing keys when looping through dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looping through a list of dictionaries and creating a dataframe, but I'm running into an issue if keys are missing. I can use "try: except:" for exception handling, but there are a lot of keys and I would prefer to use a custom function to reduce the amount of code.

I can't simply do this to to create my dataframe, by the way, due to the complexity of the list of dictionaries in my actual scenario:

```
# can't do this    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

Example data and error if keys are missing:

```
dict_list =[{'city':'smithville','zip':1234},{'city':'toonville'}]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for ind,val in enumerate(dict_list):
    city = dict_list[ind]['city']
    zip = dict_list[ind]['zip']
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'city':[city], 'zip_code':[zip]})
    df = pd.concat([df,df1])
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-0c2951af44ad> in <module>
      2 for ind,val in enumerate(dict_list):
      3     city = dict_list[ind]['city']
----> 4     zip = dict_list[ind]['zip']
      5     df1 = pd.DataFrame({'city':[city], 'zip_code':[zip]})
      6     df = pd.concat([df,df1])

KeyError: 'zip'
```

This works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for ind,val in enumerate(dict_list):
    city = dict_list[ind]['city']
    try:
        zip = dict_list[ind]['zip']
    except:
        zip = np.nan
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'city':[city], 'zip_code':[zip]})
    df = pd.concat([df,df1])

df

    city    zip_code
0   smithville  1234.0
0   toonville   NaN
```

I'd like to use a function to accomplish the above exception handling but I'm struggling with this piece. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
def get_value(x,y):
    try:
        x = y
        return(x)
    except KeyError:
        x = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame()
for ind,val in enumerate(dict_list):
    get_value(city,dict_list[ind]['city'])
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'city':[city]})
    df = pd.concat([df,df1])
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-3a634901ade7> in <module>
      1 df = pd.DataFrame()
      2 for ind,val in enumerate(dict_list):
----> 3     get_value(city,dict_list[ind]['city'])
      4     df1 = pd.DataFrame({'city':[city]})
      5     df = pd.concat([df,df1])

NameError: name 'city' is not defined
```

Comment: Use dict.get(key) this won't throw error when key is not present in dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.get` and supply a default of `np.NaN`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dict_list =[{'city':'smithville','zip':1234},{'city':'toonville'}]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for ind,val in enumerate(dict_list):
    city = dict_list[ind].get('city',np.NaN) # get if possible, default to np.NaN
    zipp = dict_list[ind].get('zip',np.NaN)  # get if possible, default to np.NaN
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'city':[city], 'zip_code':[zipp]})
    df = pd.concat([df,df1])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         city  zip_code
0  smithville    1234.0
0   toonville       NaN
```

Do no use `zip` as variable, you hide the built in zip function.

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` data structure provides this:

```
dct.get(key, value)
```

which returns `dct[key]` if the key exists, or `value` if the key doesn't exist. `value` is taken to be `None` by default.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.get` should do the trick.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dict_list =[{'city':'smithville','zip':1234},{'city':'toonville'}]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for ind,val in enumerate(dict_list):
    city = dict_list[ind].get('city', np.nan)
    zip = dict_list[ind].get('zip', np.nan)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'city':[city], 'zip_code':[zip]})
    df = pd.concat([df,df1])


>> df
    city    zip_code
0   smithville  1234.0
0   toonville   NaN
```